How do you run ffmpeg from Java, without crashing?
I try running ffmpeg from Java, and for a couple of moments everything is working fine. I want ffmpeg to record my screen, and split the recording into small clips. The command is working fine from the terminal, but when I run it from Java I get at most 3 clips. Ffmpeg doesn't write anything to the InputStream, so I have no idea what's going wrong.
public static void execute(int frameRate, int width, int height, String windowTitle) {
      String[] args = new String[]{
              path,
              "-hide_banner",
              "-f", "gdigrab",
              "-thread_queue_size", "1024",
              "-rtbufsize", "256M",
              "-framerate", "" + frameRate,
              "-offset_x", "0",
              "-offset_y", "0",
              "-video_size", "" + width + "x" + height,
              "-draw_mouse", "1",
              "-i", "title=" + windowTitle,
              "-c:v", "libx264",
              "-r", "" + frameRate,
              "-preset", "ultrafast",
              "-tune", "zerolatency",
              "-crf", "28",
              "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
              "-movflags", "+faststart",
              "-y",
              "-f", "segment",
              "-reset_timestamps", "1",
              "-segment_time", "1",
              "output%06d.mp4"
      };

      try {
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
          Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
              String line;
              BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

              System.out.println("TEST");
              try {
                  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                      System.out.println(line);

                  System.out.println("Stopping with reading");
                  input.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          });
          int exitCode = p.waitFor();
          thread.start();
          thread.join();
          if (exitCode != 0) {
              throw new RuntimeException("FFmpeg exited with code " + exitCode);
          }
      } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }

I've run the same command in the terminal. That worked fine. I ran the code above, but that resulted in ffmpeg stopping after 3 clips. It kept showing as working from the task manager. As said before, ffmpeg doesn't write anything to the InputStream, even though it normally does write a lot in the terminal. The weird thing is, when I stop my Java program, but accidentally keep ffmpeg running, it suddenly does everything I wanted it to. It didn't capture the things between stopping and closing Java, but after that it continues like it should have.

Before you do anything else, replace Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args); with new ProcessBuilder(args).inheritIO().start();.  Then remove your Thread, because using inheritIO() means you don’t need that Thread anymore.

@VGR that somehow fixed it, thanks

My guess would be that this is happening because it isn’t reading or redirecting the error stream. Then the subprocess becomes blocked because its standard error buffer is full. VGR’s suggestion should fix that, or else see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--

@TimMoore That, plus that the thread that is supposed to read from stdout isn't running until it's too late.

Oh yeah, that wasn't the case at first. But somewhere in my frustration I swapped those lines
